# Shortlisting Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2008, development-environment, intellisense

Does anyone know if there's a way in VS 2008 to shortlist the Intellisense to show only, say, events or properties? Or is there possibly a plug-in for this?

I use Intellisense over going to the documentation for classes a lot and this would just be a quicker way to find a "method to do X" or a "property for Y" without knowing its name immediately.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether Visual Assist does this or this is native to VS. But when you hover your mouse our the intellisense popup listbox, you will see buttons to show events, properties only.

[image]

Comment: It must be part of Visual Assist.  I don't see what you are describing in native VS.

Comment: edited the answer with an image, I guess this is what the question is about.

Comment: Yes, the different colors definitely suggest Visual Assist.

Comment: This is VA; I just got the demo. It works almost perfect; there's currently no keyboard shortcut for the shortlisting but otherwise it's what I was looking for, thanks!!